# Trying to get app to go back to root view if user goes to another app and returns to my app

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a simple app that has 2 Activites cMain and cPuzzle.  I would like it so if a user goes to another app, and then back to my app.  My app will alwys be at the cMain activity.

Right now in my cPuzzle activty, I have the following code to go to the cMain actvity when the user is returning from another app.

```
 protected void onPause()
   {
   super.onPause();
   finish();
   }
```

Right now I'm testing it on a kindle.  What happens is that I run my app, go to the puzzle activity, then go to another app.  When I retutn to my app, there is just a blank screen.

Answer (score 0):

Because you finished your activity and do not start another. Use intent for start needed activity cMain

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, but I'm a little confuse. My app uses finish in other parts of the code and my app will return to the pre Activety, what is different hear?